RTE Signal Fan-In received by Atomic Software Component how
RTE Signal Fan-In mechanism selects which ISignal as the received Data within the Atomic Software Component R-Port?
Relevant snippets are shown below




There is no "selection". Whenever one of the ISignals is updated, the RTE forwards the value to the corresponding ´dataElementin the depictedRPortProtototype`.
To answer the (assumed) question: both ISignals are "seen" by the software-component.

Then what is the use of constr_3514 as shown above? Which essentially telling a Single Atomic SWC R-Port cannot have two SIgnalTriggering and corresponding two ISiganlIPDU.
Is that my correct understanding?
if so, then Figure 6.94 above is contradictory looks to me.
Confused

There is no contradiction. The DataMapping uses the SystemSignal. But there can be several ISignals that refer to one SystemSignal. The constraint does NOT say that "SWC R-Port cannot have two SignalTriggering".

@user3806728, you are aware of,  that the 2 different ISignals reference the same single SystemSignal. But you need 2 different ISignals mapped by 2 different ISignalToIPduMappings to 2 different ISignalIPdus.
